# What does the bytes format “\xFF\xFF\xFF” mean and how it is interpreted?

Tags: bytes

`bytes sig =  hex"aca7da"` and `bytes sig = "\xac\xa7\xda"` seem to be the same thing, ASCII interpreted as hex. Does the format `"\xFF\xFF\xFF"` somehow code that it should be read as hex?

Answer (score 5):

the \xNN notation is used to express hexadecimal like in Javascript(Hexadecimal escape sequences).

The provided forms are the same to represent the value of :`0xaca7da`

**Difference** :

\x could be used to express a special hex(initial form) value within a string e.g : `"aca7\xd4"` which is in asci will be converted to hex `0x61636137da` so '*da*' keeps its form(not considered as a string).However, hex"" will consider the whole string in the hex form.

Comment: I think you should fix it thus: will be converted to hex `0x61636137d4` so `d4` keeps...